# Estimating arctan to below

Tags: estimation

How can I estimating 
$$
\arctan(\lVert x-y\rVert),
$$
to below (where $(x,y)\in\Omega\times\Omega, x\neq y$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n, n>1$ bounded domain)?

Can you give me a hint please?

Someone said me to use

$$
\lvert x\rvert\ll 1\Rightarrow \arctan(x)\approx x
$$
but I do not see how that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing what you need the estimate for, but one simple bound is the one suggested by the following picture:

[image: a piecewise linear lower bound for arctan]

Pick some point $P = (x_0,\arctan(x_0))$ on the graph of arctan.  Then, since arctan is concave on $[0,\infty)$ (as you can verify by computing the second derivative), it lies above the secant from the origin to $P$, as shown; also, since arctan is increasing, it lies above the horizontal line extending to the right from $P$, as shown.  This yields the lower bound
$$ \arctan(t) \ge \begin{cases}
t\arctan(x_0)/x_0 &\text{if $0\le t\le x_0$,}\\
\arctan(x_0) &\text{if $x_0\le t$.}
\end{cases} $$
Or, more compactly,
$$ \arctan(t) \ge \min(\arctan(x_0), t\arctan(x_0)/x_0) \quad\text{if $t\ge 0$.} $$
You can choose $x_0$ to suit your purposes; if you take $x_0=1$, for example, you get
$$ \arctan(t) \ge \min(\tfrac\pi4, \tfrac\pi4 t) \quad\text{if $t\ge 0$.} $$

Answer (score 0):

For some $c,d >0$ you have $\min(d,c|t|) \le \arctan |t|$.

For example, $\min( \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}, \frac{1}{2} |t| ) \le \arctan |t|$.

To see the latter, suppose $ x \ge 0$ and  let $ p(x) = x - \frac{1}{3} x^3$. Consider $\phi(x) = \arctan x - p(x)$. We have $\phi'(x) = { x^4 \over x^2+1} \ge 0$, and $\phi(0) = 0$, hence $\arctan x \ge p(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$. Furthermore, $p$ is concave and has a maximum at $x_0=\sqrt{3 \over 2 }$, hence we have $p(x) \ge {x\over x_0} p(x_0) =  \frac{1}{2} x$, for $x \in [0,x_0]$. Since $\arctan$ is increasing, we have $\arctan x \ge p(x_0) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}$ for all $x \ge x_0$. It follows that $\arctan x \ge \min(\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}, \frac{1}{2} x)$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Can you please explain that? What is $c\lvert t\rvert$?

Comment: by the way i forgot to mention that $x\neq y$

Comment: $c$ is a positive constant, $|t|$ is the absolute value of t.

Comment: any one or are c and d to be determined?... sorry, i dont see it

Comment: I added an example, to get the numbers, use the Taylor series.

Comment: I have opened the taylor series but how did you get the numbers??

Comment: do not see it ;(

Comment: I have elaborated.